# swift uigesturerecognizer не отзывается на тап

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Делаю View, которая показывала бы рейтинг. Это UIView, на которую добавлены 5 JAMSVGImageView (читай UIImageView, так как по сути разницы нет). В инициализаторе добавляю их в массив и на UIView и прикрепляю к ним UIGestureRecognizer. Выглядит так

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.transparent()

        if ratingViews.isEmpty {
            for i in 0 ..< 5 {
                let image = JAMSVGImageView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(i * 16), 0, 16, 16))
                image.userInteractionEnabled = true
                image.backgroundColor = UIColor.transparent()
                image.svgImage = JAMSVGImage(named: "istargray")

                let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "ratingPressed:")
                image.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

                ratingViews.append(image)
                addSubview(image)
            }
        }
    }
```

Сам обработчик

```
func rartingPressed(image: JAMSVGImageView) {
        print("pressed \(ratingViews.indexOf(image))")
        print("just text")
        if (User.isAuthorized && User.swimContains(product!.id)) {
            showRating(image);
            publishRating(ratingViews.indexOf(image)! + 1);
        } else {
            Toast.show(self.superview!, text: "Купите продукт, чтобы оценить его", length: Toast.SHORT)
        }
    }
```

Была мысль что не срабатывает выбор условия, но не выводятся даже голые print(). Не подскажете в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/):

> The action methods invoked must conform to one of the following signatures:
>
> - (void)handleGesture;
> - (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;

В переводе: метод, который вызовет рекогнайзер должен иметь одну из указанных выше подписей. В вашем случае метод должен быть:

```
func rartingPressed(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer)
```

как из этого получить imageView?

```
let imageView = recognizer.view as! JAMSVGImageView
```